# AVPlayer SeekToTime causes AVLayer to disappear

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I currently am using AVAssetWriter to capture my video and data. Once done, I playback my AVPlayerItem. The problem is after the first initial play and once DidItemFinishPlaying notification is called, I try to seek it back to the beginning. When I do this, the avlayer disappears instead of showing the poster frame in a paused state. Another thing I tried was doing SeektoTime when I am about to start replaying the video but I can see my live preview from my camera for about 1-2 seconds before it starts playing the video again. Here is my code.

```
let outputFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: self.outputVidFilePath)

appDel.currCamData = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsAtPath(outputFileURL.path!)
appDel.currCamDataType = "Video"
appDel.currCamDataURL = outputFileURL

self.vidPlayer.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(AVPlayerItem(URL: outputFileURL))

self.avLayer.hidden = false

self.playerTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.25, target: self, selector: #selector(CameraViewController.checkPlayerStatus), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func checkPlayerStatus()
{
    if playerTimer == nil
    {
        return
    }

    if vidPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatus.ReadyToPlay
    {
        if vidPlayer.currentItem != nil
        {
            let currentPlayItem = vidPlayer.currentItem!
            if currentPlayItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatus.ReadyToPlay
            {
                playerTimer!.invalidate()
                playerTimer = nil

                if (!playerNotificationStarted) {

                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CameraViewController.itemDidFinishPlaying(_:)), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: nil)

                    playerNotificationStarted = true

                    vidPlayer.play()
                    isVideoPlaying = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func itemDidFinishPlaying(notification :NSNotification)
{
    self.vidPlayer.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)

    self.playButton.hidden = false
    self.isVideoPlaying = false
}
```

Comment: Can anyone recommend anything for this? It has been almost a year, I still have this issue sometimes. Again, after a video is done playing it doesn't show the preview image anymore, its blank as if the player cannot find an image to display.